# Mean increases after aggregating in R

Tags: r, math

I aggregated a data frame and found that the mean increased after the aggregation. The codes and results are like this:

```
df <- read.table(text = '
var value
1   8
1   9
1   7
2   3
2   9
2   11
3   6
3   3
3   5
3   8
', header = T)

mean(df$value)
# 6.9

df1 <- aggregate(df$value, list(df$var), mean)
df1
# Group.1              x
#       1       8.000000
#       2       7.666667
#       3       5.500000

mean(df1$x)
# 7.055556
```

Can anyone tell me why `mean(df1$x)` increased a little bit compared to `mean(df$value)`? Shouldn't they be the same?

Comment: You are standardizing by different number of rows `sum(df$value)/nrow(df)` and `sum(df1$x)/nrow(df1)`

Comment: Thank you, @akrun. Now I see why. I tried the formula you provided in Excel and got the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because of the different group sizes. The third group has 4 elements and thus making the mean of means not to be equal to the population mean. Take for example a scenario where all of the groups have 3 elements,
eg

```
mean(df[1:9,2])
[1] 6.777778
```

compare to

```
mean(aggregate(value~.,df[1:9,],mean)[,2])
[1] 6.777778
```

These must be equal since all the groups have the same number of elements (ie each has 3 elements)

Answer (score 1):

The mean of the group means is not equal to the overall mean unless the group sizes are the same; however, the weighted mean of the group means is equal to the overall mean provided we weight by the group sizes.

Thus, in order to be able to retain the ability to take the original mean from the group means we also store the group sizes.  Here `df1` contains both the mean in the `value` column and the group size in the `n` column.  We then use `weighted.mean` to compute the overall mean.  We also show how to calculate the answer using `rep` as wellas two solutions which take the weighted mean without the `weighted.mean` function.

```
df1 <- transform(aggregate(cbind(n = 1, value) ~ var, df, sum), value = value / n)

mean(df$value)
## [1] 6.9

with(df1, weighted.mean(value, n))
## [1] 6.9

with(df1, mean(rep(value, n)))
## [1] 6.9

with(df1, sum(value * prop.table(n)))
## [1] 6.9

with(df1, sum(value * n) / sum(n))
## [1] 6.9
```